# git hanging on push (broken pipe) over ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I've been experiencing issues with git in combination with the bitbucket.org service lately.
I recently installed a new version of Ubuntu (after wiping completely). At first I have copied the ssh keys, but since I thought that this might cause issues, I generated a new pair and copied the new public key to bitbucket.org. The old keys are removed now.

This is what I get on `git push`

```
Counting objects: 44, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 3.33 KiB, done.
Total 33 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

At this point it takes (not actually) forever to finally display:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
```

This is my configuration shown by `git remote show origin`

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:Username/name_of_repo.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:Username/name_of_repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

A `git pull` gives "Already up-to-date." as expected.

Output of `git fsck` (as suggested by user1471175) is

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (468/468), done.
```

A very small push previously succeeded, the changeset I'm trying to push now is a bit larger, but only covers around 10 files, which never were a problem before reinstalling the OS.

What can cause these issues? It's not the bitbucket.org service right now as a colleague of mine can do actions on his machine (on the same wireless network).

If I configure git to upload via `https` instead of `ssh`, there's no issue at all, so the problem seems to be connected to `ssh`, although the pair of ssh-keys is completely new.

Comment: Does it work if you go to your config file in your .ssh and add the line *IPQoS=throughput* ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Right after the push or fetch, git seems to hang. After leaving it in that state for a while (thirty or forty minutes or so), I noticed it continued.
Try putting in ~/.ssh/config;
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
This means that every 60 seconds, your computer tries to keep a connection alive with the server you are connecting to.

My setup (client):
MBP, OS X 10.8.4
git version 1.8.3.1.448.gfb7dfaa

Server:
Sorry, I cannot help you on this one. I only know it is a linux VPS (and running cPanel).

I hope this info can help someone.

Comment: this is the answer - see also https://matt.berther.io/2013/12/29/pushing-large-git-repos-with-ssh/

Answer (score 1):

seems like remote site is not insyc with your files.

try this command first

```
git pull
```

then try

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: No, this isn't the cause. I've updated the question accordingly